AES-256 dbms_crypto output mismatches with CryptoJS
I am trying to match PL/SQL dbms_crypto with Javascript CryptoJS. I want to encrypt in JS and decrypt in PL/SQL, but for testing, I am encrypting in both to see if I can get the encrypted value to match.
I followed this as much as I could but I am still stuck.
dbms_crypto output mismatches with crypto-js
PLSQL
    FUNCTION cl_encrypt (p_string VARCHAR2, p_key VARCHAR2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
        lv_whats_my_name    VARCHAR2 (100) := 'cl_utilities.cl_encrypt';
        v_encrypted_raw     RAW (32000);
        v_key               RAW (320);
        v_encryption_type   PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt_aes256 + DBMS_CRYPTO.chain_cbc + DBMS_CRYPTO.pad_pkcs5;
    BEGIN
        v_key   := RAWTOHEX (UTL_I18N.string_to_raw (p_key, 'AL32UTF8'));
        v_encrypted_raw   :=
            DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt (src => UTL_I18N.string_to_raw (p_string, 'AL32UTF8'), typ => v_encryption_type, key => v_key,iv=>utl_raw.cast_to_raw(1));

       RETURN UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (v_encrypted_raw));

    END;

Javascript
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const key = 'some key phrase to 0129034676438'
const message = 'bob is your uncle'
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    message,
   CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse( Buffer.from(key).toString('hex')),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(1), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

console.log("encrypted vaule :: " + encrypted );


Input:
Key : 'some key phrase to 0129034676438'
message: 'bob is your uncle'
iv: 1

PL/SQL Encrypted value:
UiJjrdgefVCcY1aJNuIt+oPPAPNOtnVTsE1g3sOwxiU= 

JavaScript value
3UcXtyd9amnyjCYXKqi4ZrqB48ZerohDON80i1h4v2U=


The IV must be a 16 bytes sequence for AES. Is this condition fulfilled by utl_raw.cast_to_raw(1)? If yes, what is the IV (e.g. hex encoded). If the IV has a different length, PL/SQL may somehow correct the value so that a different IV is used on the CryptoJS side. In this case use a 16 bytes IV.

This fixed my issue.  Thank you very much.
